# IMU alignment methods

Tags: imu

I have an IMU that is outputting the following for its measurements:

```
accelx= 0.000909228 (g's)
accely= -0.000786797 (g's)
accelz= -0.999432 (g's)
rotx= 0.000375827 (radians/second)
roty= -0.000894705 (radians/second)
rotz= -0.000896965 (radians/second)
```

I would like to calculate the roll, pitch and yaw and after that the orientation matrix of the body frame relative to the NED frame.

So I do

```
roll = atan2(-accely,-accelz);
pitch =atan2(-accelx/sqrt(pow(accely,2)+pow(accelz,2)));
sinyaw = -rotycos(roll)+rotzsin(roll);
cosyaw = rotxcos(pitch)+rotysin(roll)sin(pitch)+rotzcos(roll)*sin(pitch);
yaw = atan2(sinyaw,cosyaw);
```

and I get:

```
roll = 0.000787244
pitch = -0.000909744
yaw = 1.17206
```

in radians.

However the IMU is also outputting what *it* calculates for roll, pitch and yaw.

From the IMU, I get:

```
roll: -0.00261682
pitch: -0.00310018
yaw: 2.45783
```

Why is there is a mismatch between my roll, pitch and yaw and that of the IMU's?

Additionally, I found this formula for the initial orientation matrix.

[image: Initial orientation matrix formula]

Which way of calculating the orientation matrix is more correct.
`R1(roll)*R2(pitch)*R3(yaw)`, or the form above?

Comment: The present  rol, pitch and yaw as the IMU yields can not depend on the present acceleration as the acceleration impacts only future roll, pitch and yaw values. Try to understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Tait-Bryan_angles and use only _rotx, roty, rotz_ for your calculation.

Comment: In the box just below the "So I do", you calculate the pitch as a function of a variable accel_x which doesn't seem to be defined. Is it a typo?

Comment: Are there magnetometer outputs available as well?

Comment: @Christo, Yes that is a typo.

Comment: @Christo. There are also magnetometer ouputs

Comment: @Christo, I am confused about the answer. could please help on this, thanks. as you mentioned, there are 2 phases to calc pose(roll, pitch, and yaw), w/o accelerating and w/ accelerating.
1) w/o accelerating phase, fx/fy/fz should be zero in theory, while they are not due to bias/noise or some other factors. then can use this accelerometer measurements to init heading?
2) w accelerating phase, say it is okay for step1, we should get ϕ0,θ0,ψ0, then how to define the ϕ,θ,ψ used in equation at the right side of "="? use the same equation used in step1 to get a real-time value(for example, θt), th

Comment: When the IMU is stationary it still measures gravity. So let's say your IMU is sitting on a table. Let's say it's z (down axis) is aligned with gravity.  Without biases it would measure [0,0,-9.8] m/s^2

Comment: @rielt12, thanks, I also got this point yesterday. but how about the angle value used for moving state( ϕ,θ,ψ)?

Comment: @scorpio are you asking how to initialize roll, pitch and yaw when moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roll and pitch angles that you calculate using the accelerometer measurements will only be correct if (1) the IMU is non-accelerating (e.g., stationary), and (2) the accelerometer measurements are perfect. Thus, they can only be used to initialize the tilt (roll and pitch) of the IMU, not to calculate roll and pitch during acceleration. An external measurement of yaw angle is required to initialize the yaw angle.

See these answers:

- [What information an IMU gives to a drone?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/10047/13926)
- [Multicopter: What  are Euler angles used for?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/12705/13926)

for some background.

Say the accelerometer measurements are $f_x$, $f_y$, and $f_z$; the gyro measurements are $\omega_x$, $\omega_y$, and $\omega_z$, and the magmetometer measuremenst are $b_x$, $b_y$, and $b_z$.  The roll angle ($\phi$) and pitch ($\theta$) angle can be initialized if the IMU is not accelerating using 
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_0 &=& \tan^{-1}\left(f_y/f_z\right) \\
\theta_0 &=& \tan^{-1}\left(-f_x/\sqrt{f_y^2+f_z^2}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
The yaw angle ($\psi$) can be initialized using the magnetometer measurements. Given the roll and pitch angles, the magnetic heading ($\psi_m$) can be calculated from $b_x$, $b_y$, and $b_z$. Given the magnetic declination at the system location, the true heading (or initial yaw angle, $\psi_o$) can be calculated.

Once the IMU is initalized in an unaccelerated state, the gyro measurements can be used to calculate the rates of change of the Euler angles while the IMU is moving:
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot\phi &=& \omega_x +\tan\theta\sin\phi\,\omega_y +\tan\theta\cos\phi\,\omega_z \\  
\dot\theta &=& \cos\phi\,\omega_y -\sin\phi\,\omega_z \\ 
\dot\psi   &=& \sec\theta\sin\phi\,\omega_y +\sec\theta\cos\phi\,\omega_z 
\end{eqnarray}
The rates of change of the Euler angles are then numerically integrated to propagate the Euler angles.  The coordinate transformation matrix at each instant of time can then be obtained from the Euler angles.

This will work if your IMU never pitches up or down to $\pm90^\circ$.  In that case it will be better to calculate and propagate quaternions instead of Euler angles. (Euler angles can always be calculated from the quaternions.)

Alas, the gyros are not perfect.  Say that the gyros have bias errors, then these bias errors will also be integrated with time to result in the Euler angled "drifting".  For this reason, an extended Kalman filter is often used to calculate the orientation of the IMU, aided by other measurements (magnetometer, accelerometer, and a GPS, for example). But that's another topic :)